# Maxima: shuffle order of elements in a list?

Tags: list, function, shuffle, maxima, wxmaxima

### Question

Given a list `L:[a,b,c,d,e,f]` **is there a built in way of randomly shuffling the elements of the list?** Something like:

```
M:random_order(L);
    > [ b, c, d, a, e, f]
```

I checked the documentation for [Functions and Variables for Lists](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_21.html#Functions-and-Variables-for-Lists) for any built in option for shuffling the order of elements in a list, but didn't see anything obvious.

---

### Context

I'm trying to generate lists of `x` terms whose maximal sum is `s`. Right now, I'm doing this by creating a list where each term is a random number between 1 and the max value that ensures that, if the remaining terms have a minimal value of 1, then the sum will be, at most, `s`:

```
/* `x` is the total number of terms; `s` is the max sum */
gen_val(x, s):=block([x:x, s:s, vals:makelist(nul,i,x) ], 
  
   /* 
      the first value is a random integer in [1, (s-x)], if 
      vals[1] = (s-x), then all remaining terms have to be equal to 1 
   */
   vals[1]: 1 + random(s-x),
   
  /* 
     subsequent terms are assigned in the same way, subtracting the sum of 
     previously assigned values, as well as reserving at least 1 unit for 
     each remaining term 
  */
  for i:2 thru x
  do vals[i]:1 + random(s-sum(vals[k],k,1,i-1)-(x-i+1)),
  
  /* return the list */
  vals
);
```

However, this generates lists where earlier terms (*i.e.* lower index) have a higher probability of having higher values; whereas I'd like a more even distribution of the values.

The simplest solution I could think of was simply shuffling the elements of the `vals` list; however, I'd be equally interested in any other method that achieves this desired result (*i.e.* a list of `x` terms whose sum is, at most, `s`).

The even broader context is the problem of dividing an interval of the number line into sub-intervals. I decided to take the length of the interval and the number of partitions as my variables for building the sub-intervals, hence the goal, stated above. If `I = [a, b]` is the full interval, then for any `c`, `d` such that `c+d =< b-a` we can define the subintervals `[a, a+c]`, `[a+c, a+c+d]`, `[a+c+d, b]`

Comment: The function to put items in a random order is `random_permutation`. About constructing partitions of intervals, how about `unique (makelist (a + 1 + random (b - 1 - a), n - 1))` where `n` is the number of subintervals? When `b - a` is an integer, then the random numbers are integers as well; otherwise, `b - a` must be a float, and the random numbers are floats. I guess you might need to adjust the +/- 1 business depending on exactly how you want the results to be.